# ngClass toggle particular element only while using ngFor Angular5

Tags: angular, angular5, ngfor, ng-class

I want to toggle particular element when clicked on click event and its in loop to toggle all class,  means all div show. Here is my code

```html
<div *ngFor="let xyz of abc">
    <span (click)="showOptions = !showOptions"></span>
    <ul [ngClass]="{show:showOptions}">
        <li> some text</li>
    </ul>
    <div>{{xyz}}</div>
</div>
```

It should open next element not all!!
any help?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you are using one boolean for each of your ngFor loop element. You should try to add a boolean field to your array elements:

```js
abc = [
    {
        text: 'el1',
        show: false
    },
    {
        text: 'el2',
        show: false
    },
    {
        text: 'el3',
        show: false
    },
]
```

In your template :

```html
<div *ngFor="let xyz of abc">
    <span (click)="xyz.show = !xyz.show"></span>
    <ul [ngClass]="{show:xyz.show}">
        <li>{{xyz.text}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Note**

You could also use `ngIf` to display/hide your options list:

```html
<ul *ngIf="xyz.show">
```

Comment: @Augustine, I can't add "show: false" in object element, it will be typical to add, because this bunch of object has heavy hierarchy and may in thousands!! any another idea

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your comment. The field can easily be added with a for loop, in the subscribe function. As far as I know, there is no other simple way to do it.